# Deploy a .aspx page to the Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I am new to sharepoint and have a scenario

1) I have a aspx page which displays some data from a xml.

2) The data is populated in a table in the aspx page using a code behind .cs file.

3) I use some dll's which I have made to access the data.

**Note:- This things are done on my local pc which does not have a sharepoint server installed.**

Now my question is

1) I want a way using which I can use this page as a webpart in a sharepoint site.

2) Can you please guide me a by which the compiled dll of the web application can be used as webpart.

**Note:- I have access to put files on the server but cannot develop anything on that**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the User Control in SharePoint and add it to your site page..

OR

Use Visual Studio and create an empty SharePoint project (deploy as farm solution).

Then, right click project and add mapped layouts folder.

Rename this folder to whatever name you want to appear (this folder will get created on the servers layout folder in the hive) after you deploy the solution.

Add your aspx page and cs into this folder

Then, double click on package.package (its inside package, above layouts folder, under project)--> Advanced --> Add (existing assembly) and add your dll references here.(this will add the dlls under your sites sharepoint web.config.

After deploy, you can access page using: `http://sharepointsite/_layouts/foldername/youraspxfilename.aspx`

Let us know about the progress.

Comment: The thing here is that I dont have access to sharepoint server so it would never let me create an empty sharepoint project. So is there any way using sharepoint designer that I can put the pages developed on my visual studio(on local machine without sharepoint server) on the server so that I can access these pages in my sharepoint site.

Comment: OK, you can create empty project on your dev machine and maybe use something like an ascx user control. Then, using sharepoint designer, create a new site page and you can add the user control on your page.

Comment: Ok how about this. I create a ASP.NET project write my logic in it and compile now I create a deployment package of my website and then the dll's in my bin will be copied to the server's bin and then put the .aspx page into the sharepoint site with the help of sharepoint designer and then link the deployment dll into the aspx page. I think this will do